# PostgreSQL IF statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, plpgsql

How can I do such query in Postgres?

```
IF (select count(*) from orders) > 0
THEN
  DELETE from orders
ELSE 
  INSERT INTO orders values (1,2,3);
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have IF, instead use a SELECT CASE WHEN statement, as in: `SELECT CASE WHEN 50<100 THEN 5 ELSE 10 END;` which allows a: `SELECT CASE WHEN 50<(select count(*) from sometable) THEN 5 ELSE 10 END from mytable;`

Answer (score 222, accepted):

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM orders) THEN
      DELETE FROM orders;
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,2,3);
   END IF;
END
$do$
```

There are no procedural elements in standard SQL. The [`IF` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) is part of the default procedural language PL/pgSQL. You need to create a function or execute an ad-hoc statement with the [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command.

You need a semicolon (`;`) at the end of each statement in plpgsql ([except for the final `END`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html)).

You need `END IF;` at the end of the `IF` statement.

A sub-select must be surrounded by parentheses:

```
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM orders) > 0 ...
```

Or:

```
    IF (SELECT count(*) > 0 FROM orders) ...
```

This is equivalent and much faster, though:

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM orders) ...
```

#### Alternative

The additional `SELECT` is not needed. This does the same, faster:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM orders;
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,2,3);
   END IF;
END
$do$
```

Though unlikely, concurrent transactions writing to the same table may interfere. To be absolutely sure, [write-lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-lock.html) the table in the same transaction before proceeding as demonstrated.

Comment: Doesn't work. I got ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 89:       %do%

Comment: @Luffydude: And where would you find `%` in my code? IOW: The above statements work, you introduced an unrelated syntax error. Looks like you typed `%do%` instead of `$do$`.

Comment: Wondering why PostgreSQL can't make it easier like T-SQL? An obstacle for many wants to jump on pg.

Answer (score 83):

Just to help if anyone stumble on this question like me,
if you want to use if in PostgreSQL, you use "CASE"

```
select 
    case
        when stage = 1 then 'running'
        when stage = 2 then 'done'
        when stage = 3 then 'stopped'
    else 
        'not running'
    end as run_status from processes
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question. IF statement is different than CASE WHEN. CASE cannot be used outside the query.

Answer (score 16):

You could also use the the basic structure for the PL/pgSQL CASE with [anonymous code block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) procedure block:

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN boolean-expression THEN
          statements;
        WHEN boolean-expression THEN
          statements;
        ...
        ELSE
          statements;
    END CASE;
END $$;
```

References:

1. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html
2. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Answer (score 10):

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

```
IF boolean-expression THEN
    statements
ELSE
    statements
END IF;
```

So in your above example the code should look as follows:

```
IF select count(*) from orders > 0
THEN
  DELETE from orders
ELSE 
  INSERT INTO orders values (1,2,3);
END IF;
```

You were missing: **END IF;**

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but it doesn't work. ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if"

Comment: 1. please don't link beta docs; 2. your example needs to be enclosed in [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) to be usable as a SQL statement and not inside a PL/pgSQL function.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev it was the most recent documentation, available on the site.  Further I was building off of the OP's initial post to show the correct syntax for the statement.

Comment: @VladimirTsukanov are you assigning the value from the select into a variable?

Comment: I am also getting the same error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "if" –`

Comment: all who got `ERROR` - this is because you should use it inside function.  Moreover - If you use 9.0+ then you can use DO to run in it in place by executing an inline function: `DO $$ BEGIN ... END $$;`