# If statements in postgres throw error

Tags: database, postgresql, if-statement

I'm trying to run a statement to this effect:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LeadCustomer WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND Surname = 'Smith') THEN
    SELECT * FROM LeadCustomer WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND Surname = 'Smith';
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO LeadCustomer (Firstname, Surname, BillingAddress, email) VALUES ('John', 'Smith', '6 Brewery close, Buxton, Norfolk', 'cmp.testing@example.com');;
END IF;
```

and it throws the error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299037/postgresql-if-statement) but the format suggested in those answers don't seem to work either. Was wondering if anyone could tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: you have a double ;; - not sure that matters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`If` is part of the plpgsql language. It will only work inside a plpgsql function:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [CASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) expression.

Comment: I don't think case would allow me to do quite the same thing, though?

Comment: In fact, CASE, doesn't seem to want to be used unless it's already in another statement....