# Conditional INSERT or SELECT like in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do an insert using a `CASE` statement in PostgreSQL.

I am trying to do an insert if the count of my result set is equal to zero. If it isn't equal to zero, then I just want to do a select of the max time on that table.

```
select
    case
        when (select count(*) from x where TableName = 'p' ) > 0
              then
             (select    MaxDataDate from    x where TableName = 'p' ) 
        when (select count(*) from s where TableName = 'p') = 0
              then
             (insert into x values('p','1900-01-01'))
end
```

Comment: Please share some sample data, what exactly you wanna do?

Comment: what database engine are you using,please put in tag, that would be helpful

Comment: You cannot write a query that selects or inserts whether the test validates or not. You'll have to test your conditions, and then execute the relevant query.

Comment: How can I do it then?

Comment: @user3581913 . . . A single query cannot both return data and insert data at the same time.  You need to decide what you want the query to do.

Comment: I inserted more comments. Thank you

Comment: There you should find the answer you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299037/postgresql-if-statement

Comment: We would need the table definitions to answer that properly. What you get with \d x and \d in psql. Or is `s` just a typo? And don't you want anything returned form the `INSERT` statement? Also, your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Could be translated to pure SQL with a [data-modyfying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) like this:

```
WITH sel AS (SELECT maxdatadate FROM x where tablename = 'p')
,    ins AS (
    INSERT INTO x (?column_name1?, ?column_name2?)
    SELECT 'p'::?type1?, '1900-01-01'::?type2?
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ins)
    AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM s WHERE tablename = 'p')
    )
SELECT * FROM ins;
```

Fill in missing information. `?` marks the spots.

Assuming `x.tablename` is unique. Otherwise, your 2nd `SELECT` statement would be nonsense.

The alternative would be a procedural solution in a plpgsql function or a `DO` statement [like @X.L.Ant already hinted in his comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344707/doing-an-insert-with-a-case-statement-in-sql#comment35751091_23344707)