# Conditional Update in SQL with if or case

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql-10

My question is if there is a way to do a conditional update for example

```
if existence = true 
    then update market set exitdate = now(), existence = false
    else then update market set exitdate = null, existence = true
```

For more that I look for, I can't find something similar to my code.

Comment: You can use merge

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299037/postgresql-if-statement)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with the next code...

```
UPDATE market 
SET exitdate = CASE WHEN existence = true AND boxnumm = xxxx then now() else null END,
    existence = CASE WHEN exitdate <> null AND boxnumm = xxxx then false else true END
    WHERE boxnumm = xxxx
;
```