# Execute Postgres query only if a lock is granted

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, locking

I have some SQL queries which will be executed in a clustered environment. I'm trying to use a Postgres advisory lock to prevent multiple executions of these queries.

- Begin transaction.
- Execute `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock` and check the boolean return value.
- If `true` (the lock is acquired), then proceed with the actual business-logic queries (arbitrary).
- If `false` (another instance is already holding the exclusive lock), then do nothing.
- End transaction.

Note that I'm using the non-blocking `_try_` variant which returns a boolean. If the lock is not immediately available, some other instance is already executing the command, so nothing needs to be done.

The question "[PostgreSQL IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299037/postgresql-if-statement)" suggests embedding a PL/pgSQL `IF` clause using `DO`. Is there a way to do this without this extra complexity?