# how to execute multiple statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like below:

```
if extract(dow from current_date)=1 then
select * form dev
else
select * from dev1
end if
```

Error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if" LINE 1: if extract(dow from
>   current_date)=1 then

How can I perform `ddl` and `dml` operation in single execution?

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL. Try rewriting it into one or two `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: You seem to think SQL is a programming language. Maybe have a look at PL/pgSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11299037/1025391

Comment: This seems like a rather strange request and might indicate a badly designed data model.

Comment: Use conditional expression provided by postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html