# IF else inside case when statement

Tags: postgresql

Can we use IF ELSE condition inside CASE statement  like below format

```
case when DATENAME(SECOND, GETDATE()) IN (N'Saturday', N'Sunday') 
        then if () then
              else if then 
           else 
          end,

    else 
    'Weekday'
 end
```

Comment: Case *expression*. [Please fix your mental model]

Comment: You do that with another CASE inside the outer CASE.

Comment: The `IF` statement is a part of the procedural language PL/pgSQL. If you really want to use an `IF` statement in your logic, you need to create a function or execute an ad-hoc statement with the `DO` command. See this threat https://stackoverflow.com/a/11299968/8748450 for alternative and see this tutorial how to use `DO` https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/plpgsql-if-else-statements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can nest CASE expressions, or use multiple tests if appropriate.
These 2 example give the same result.

```
select 
  x,y,
  case 
    when x = 1 then
      case when y = 1 then 11
      else 12 
      end
    when x = 2 then
      case when y = 1 then 21
      else 22
      end
  else 99 end myExression
from test;
```

| x | y | myexression |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 1 | 21 |
| 2 | 2 | 22 |
| null | null | 99 |

```
select 
  x,y,
  case
    when x = 1 and y = 1 then 11
    when x = 1 and y = 2 then 12
    when x = 2 and y = 1 then 21
    when x = 2 and y = 2 then 22
    else 99 
  end myExpression
from test;
```

| x | y | myexpression |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 1 | 21 |
| 2 | 2 | 22 |
| null | null | 99 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=88487eaa08d97dd5a224c2dfd076d960)*