# Postgresql select from based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to run a given select statement based on condition?

If a condition (which comes from table_A) is true then select from table_B otherwise from table_C. Tables have no common column.

Something like this

```
select case when table_A.flag=true then   
    (select * from table_B ) 
    else
    (select * from table_C ) 
    end
from table_A where ...
```

The above one will fail of course :   `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Comment: @Shmiel yes, updated the example

Comment: Did you try using an `if` statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299037/postgresql-if-statement)

Comment: @Shmiel sorry, forgot to mention it should be plain sql

Comment: This `if` statement is plain sql. It would work as follows `if (select <column> from <table>) = <condition> then (select * from table) else (select * from other_table)`

Comment: Do these tables have the exact same columns (or are the columns you want from them exactly the same)?

Comment: @EdmCoff yes same columns

Comment: @shmiel  it is not.   result: 'syntax error at or near "if" '

Comment: @Shmiel `if` is not part of standard SQL (at least for PostgreSQL). It is part of pl/pgSQL of PostgreSQL. `case` does the same job as `if` in standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns are the same, you could use a `UNION`. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_B
WHERE (SELECT flag FROM Table_A) = true
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Table_C
WHERE (SELECT flag FROM Table_A) <> true
```

I'm assuming here that `Table_A` has only one row, but you could adjust the subquery in the `WHERE` conditions to get the `flag` however you need it.

The basic idea is that you set up the two conditions so that only one of them is true at a time (based on your `flag`). So, even though it is a `UNION`, only one part of the query will return results and you either end up with `Table_B` or `Table_C`.